# what is the use of @StringRes in javadoc?

Tags: java, android, annotations

I wonder for a method like `MyDialog(Context context, @StringRes int message)`, what does @StringRes exactly do? My impression is that if it is not there, the programmer might think message is a number or something? Is that only a hint for the developer or does it do a more important job?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringRes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it right, these annotations **will help developer** who will use it, also it will help **in code inspection** tools like **Lint**, which is supported by IDE Android Studio itself and **while building command line**

Below is except from Android documentation

> Using code inspections tools such as Lint can help you find problems
>   and improve your code, but inspection tools can only infer so much.
>   Android resource IDs, for example, use an int to identify strings,
>   graphics, colors, and other resource types, so inspection tools cannot
>   tell when you have specified a string resource where you should have
>   specified a color. This situation means that your app may render
>   incorrectly or fail to run at all, even if you use code inspection.
>
> Annotations allow you to provide hints to code inspections tools like
>   Lint, to help detect these more subtle code problems. They are added
>   as metadata tags that you attach to variables, parameters, and return
>   values to inspect method return values, passed parameters, local
>   variables, and fields. When used with code inspections tools,
>   annotations can help you detect problems, such as null pointer
>   exceptions and resource type conflicts.
>
> Android supports a variety of annotations through the Annotations
>   Support Library. You can access the library through the
>   android.support.annotation package.

Answer (score 10):

`@StringRes` indicates that the integer to be passed is a String Resource (from `values/strings.xml`). For Example:

```
R.string.title
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringRes.html